# How can I insert records in a specific table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2008-r2

I have this image from my database :

[image]

On this table where I upload many text files (`.txt`) throught SSIS. 
Actually I have done it and looks like the image. Each file has like name `RC1960196012070801`, `RC196017080401`,etc. I have already stored every file in the table like the image.
Now If you realize each file (`.txt`) could be with many records or few records.
My question is: 
How I could save on my real table where I have all the fields, the records like my example ?

I want to get the name of each name "RC...." and save it with the records that belong with the respective

Example :

```
1.10110096 -  39896804  -  7000000003  -  00000427   - RC196012070801 
1.10394332 -  40180191  -  7000000005  -  00004071   - RC196012070801 

1.12316381 -  163448816  - 7000000982  -  00000982   - RC196017080401
```

Please help me with this problem .

Thank you so much in advance!!

Comment: MySQL and ms sql server are two different products. I removed MySQL because you had more ms sql server related tags. If you do use MySQL, then pls add that tag back and remove all sql server related ones.

Comment: Well, I read your question 4 times, but still can't understand it, also we don't know how those files looks like or your table too, should we guess?

Comment: Hello Sami Please read again my question. The example shows how is the way to save my data. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Set the delimiter of your import to '~' instead of ',' and then should have a column representative of each column in your files.